# displaying errors for hidden HTML5 hidden text fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I alert a error message for a field where  display is hidden (none)

For example :

```
<form>
    <td style="display:none;">
        <input id="put_supp" type="text" autocomplete="false" class="form-control" name="supplier[0]" placeholder=""  required>
    </td>
</form>
```

Comment: Could swear I have seen this question twice already today?

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340921

Comment: How do you submit the form? I dont see a submit button for example??

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly Yes, this was posted few hours before and then deleted. I wanted to make it more clear. This is the code with submit button:  <form>
    <td style="display:none;">
        <input id="put_supp" type="text" autocomplete="false" class="form-control" name="supplier[0]" placeholder=""  required>
    </td>   
  <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_form">Submit</button></center> <br> </form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("get_supp").value;
 document.getElementById("put_supp").value = x;
 document.getElementById("put_supp1").value = x;
}
```

to

```
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("get_supp").value;
 if (x == "") { alert("PLEASE FILL OUT ALL FIELDS"); }
 else {
  document.getElementById("put_supp").value = x;
  document.getElementById("put_supp1").value = x;
 }
}
```

Comment: hi thankyou sounds very logical, tried it  but doesn't work at all.

Comment: it sounds like the function doesn't run, because that should work just fine. how do you run the function? button press, form submit, etc..? @KTE

Comment: it runs as onkeyup like this  <input type="text" id="get_supp" required onkeyup="myFunction()" >

Comment: so your triggering it and it's not doing anything? can you see any errors in the javascript console?